# why scrolledtext is not increasing it's size(weight) in tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

How to dynamically adjust the size of widgets which are inside the tabs. Here I have created a tab in that I am fitting the widgets. whenever I am increasing the size of the root window by using size grip the scrolled text widget is not increasing its size even though I am using reconfigure and columnconfigure. How to do this

Thanks

```
from __future__ import division
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import scrolledtext
import socket
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import simpledialog
from tkinter.filedialog import asksaveasfile
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfile 
from tkinter.font import Font
from PIL import Image,ImageTk

def on_configure(event):

    canvas.configure(scrollregion=canvas.bbox('all'))

    new_width = int(event.width)
    new_height = int(event.height)
    wd = int(w1.place_info().get('x'))

    if new_width == 1273:
        w1.place(x=(new_width-280))

    elif new_width > 1280:
        w1.place(x=(new_width-280))


    cip = int(w1.place_info().get('x'))
    print('Current :',cip)
    print(new_width,new_height)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    global screen_width,screen_height
    global a0,a1,t0,count
    count=0
    a0=[]
    a1=[]
    t0=[]
    root = tk.Tk()

    screen_width = root.winfo_screenwidth()
    screen_height = root.winfo_screenheight()

    root.minsize(1300,715)

    root.title('tkinter GUI')
    colour = 'tomato3'

    gif= 'E:\PYTHON\data transfer\Sys1\Framework\dist\cat.jpg'

    im=Image.open(gif)
    im_width = im.width

    photo=ImageTk.PhotoImage(im)

    scrollbary = Scrollbar(root, orient = tk.VERTICAL)
    scrollbarx = Scrollbar(root,orient = tk.HORIZONTAL)
    sizegrip = ttk.Sizegrip(root)
    canvas = tk.Canvas(root,yscrollcommand = scrollbary.set,
                       xscrollcommand = scrollbarx.set)
    scrollbary.config(command=canvas.yview)
    scrollbarx.config(command=canvas.xview)

    scrollbary.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill='y',expand = tk.FALSE)

    scrollbarx.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM,fill = 'x',expand = tk.FALSE)
    sizegrip.pack(side = tk.BOTTOM, anchor = "se")
    canvas.pack(side=tk.LEFT, padx=5, pady=5,fill=tk.BOTH, expand=tk.TRUE)

    frame = tk.Frame(canvas,height=520,width=1300)
    canvas.create_window((0,0), window=frame, anchor='nw')

    l_font = Font(frame,family="Helvetica", size=20,weight='bold')

    labe1 = tk.Label(frame, text="label_1", foreground="BLUE",font=l_font)

    labe2 = tk.Label(frame, text="label_2", foreground="red",font=l_font)
    labe3 = tk.Label(frame, text="label_3", foreground="green", font=l_font)

    labe1.place(x=10,y=1)
    labe2.place(x=200,y=40)
    labe3.place(x=180,y=81)

    w1 = tk.Label(frame, image=photo)

    w1.place(x=995,y=1)
    canvas.bind('<Configure>', on_configure)

    frame_width = root.winfo_width()
    frame_height = root.winfo_height()
    print('frame: ',frame_width,frame_height)
    tabControl = ttk.Notebook(frame,width=screen_width,height=(screen_height-180))

    tab1 = Frame(tabControl) 

    labe6 = Label(tab1, text='Text1', fg='red',font=("helvetica", 10, 'bold'))
    labe6.grid(row = 0,column = 0,sticky = NW)

    RT = scrolledtext.ScrolledText(tab1, wrap=NONE,height = 11,width = 200)
    RT.grid(row=1, column=0,sticky = NW)


    labe7 = Label(tab1, text='text2', fg='red',font=("helvetica", 10, 'bold'))
    labe7.grid(row = 2,column = 0,sticky = NW)

    ET = scrolledtext.ScrolledText(tab1, wrap=NONE,height = 11,width = 200)
    ET.grid(row=3, column=0,sticky = NW)

    tab1.rowconfigure('all', weight=10)
    tab1.columnconfigure('all', weight=10)
    tab1.grid(row=0, column=0)

    tabControl.add(tab1, text='tab_1')
    tabControl.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=tk.YES,pady=135)


    root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You have set the `sticky` attribute to `NW` for the scrolledtext widget, meaning it will only "stick" to the top and bottom of the space it has been allocated. If you want it to fill all of the space given to it, you need to use the string `"nsew"` or the constant `NSEW`

Comment: If i use stickey = NSEW then, text widget is occupying the total screen width. But i want to set the text widget initially with in the boundary of the 1300x715. whenever i am increasing the size the text widget size has to be increased.

Comment: @ShivPj: when you use `sticky=NSEW` the only possible thing that can happen is that it fills its containing frame, which is what you asked about.  It cannot be larger than the widget it is in. If it seems to be taking up more, that means that the containing frame is taking up more.

Comment: Thanks, how can i increase the size of scrolledtext widget size while increasing the size of root window. please guide me

Comment: @ShivPj: I don't understand your question. My answer shows you how to increase the size of the text widget when its containing widget grows. I don't think your problem is with the text widget, it's with some of your other widgets.